# what is the best way to deal with removing objects in multiple arrays?

Tags: objective-c

I've got a class that generates a bunch of objects of random types and stores them (well-- references to them) in an array.  As it's doing this, it also stores references to them in an array specific to their type.

Later, each array that is type-specific is iterated over and the objects in them have their x position decremented.  Within that loop, if they are on the screen, they are added to yet another array of visible objects.  Once they go off the screen they are removed from that visible object array.

The rule of my game is: an object can only be destroyed when it's visible. so when an attempt to destroy an object is made, it searches the visible object array and attempts to locate the object, if it's found then it is removed.

The problem is, once the object has been removed from the "visible array", the "type-specific" array continues to be looped over and all those objects get their x position decremented-- even though an object might no longer on the screen.

I am wondering what the best way to remove all references to the object is?  I was hesitant to go through all the arrays and call "removeObjectIdenticalTo" on them...  My initial solution was to just add a BOOL property to my object "destroyed", and set that to YES if it's been destroyed while on screen, and then have my x decrementing looop skip objects that have been destroyed....  But I started wondering if that's not the best approach as far as memory management goes since that object is sticking around longer than it needs to......

How should one deal with this?

Comment: Maybe it'd help if you added some code showing what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This may work if you started by storing all of the objects in a dictionary. Following that, add a property to the objects (that are being passed around) that contains a NSString identical to the dictionary key for the array that it lives in.

Then all you would have to do is:

```
NSMutable *array = [dicionary objectForKey:object.dictionaryKeyString];
//then remove the object from *array
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was hesitant to go through all the arrays and call "removeObjectIdenticalTo" on them

Why? Is it because you imagine this is inefficient? How do you know?

However, for true efficiency, and assuming the objects are all different objects, use NSSet, not NSArray. Access to a particular object is guaranteed efficient.